# How to get x axis labels in multiple line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the very long x axis label to multiple line as show in the encircled right image:

[image: Example image]

The code which I'm using currently:

```
ax = cluster3.plot(x='Neighborhood',y=['Population'],kind='bar',alpha=0.75,title='Population of Each Neighborhood',figsize=(15, 10))
ax.set_ylabel('Population')
```

cluster3 is the dataframe which has the Neighborhood column

Answer (score 13):

Check this image:
[image: For wrapping]

Or

```
df['cluster3'] = ['\n'.join(wrap(x, 12)) for x in  df['cluster3'])
```

apply this to your labels column to wrap the labels.

Comment: Also, you may want to use `textwrap.fill()`, which (quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill)) "*is shorthand for `"\n".join(wrap(text, ...))`*".

Comment: @Strange Please consider not posting pictures of code. This is bad practice, prevents copy/pasting and wastes storage. You may consider writing the code as text to improve your answer (and keep the histogram picture of course).

Answer (score 1):

Add a line break by adding `"\n"` to your respective labels and the position where you want the line break

If you want to make it a rule to add a line break every x characters, this will work for you:

```
def insert_linebreak(string, lengLabel=48):
    return '\n'.join(string[i:i+lengLabel] for i in xrange(0, len(string), every))
```

Comment: The labels are coming from a dataframe(cluster3). Can you suggest any way to add the "\n" to the labels?

Answer (score 0):

For any long label, put the `\n` character where you want the line to break. For example "All creatures from out of space" may become "All creatures\nfrom out of space".